# Set selected image in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller, swift2

I am trying to set a different image as `selectedImage`, I found this script to put in AppDelegate:

```
var tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as UITabBarController
let tabItems = tabBarController.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]

tabItems[2].selectedImage = UIImage(named: "image.png")
```

But it does not work.

Am I missing something obvious or made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well never mind, the "Selected Image" Box in Xcode works now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by adding this line instead of tabItems[2].selectedImage = UIImage(named: "image.png")

```
var selectedBG = UIImage(named:””)
UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = selectedBG
```